# Multi-Module Task Dependencies

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I want the outputs of one task to be available to an identical task in another submodule.

I'm trying to make yet-another plugin for compilation (of C/++, `.hs`, `.coffee`, `.js` et al) and source code generation.
So, I'm making a plugin and task/s that (so far) generate `CMakeLists.txt`, `Android.mk`, `.vcxproj` or whatever for each module to build the source code.

I have a multi-module build for this.
I can reach around and find the tasks from "other" submodules, but, I can't seem to enforce any execution order.

So, with ...

- root project: RootModule

  - sub project: NativeCommandLine (requires SharedModule)
  - sub project: NativeGUI (requires SharedModule)
  - sub project: SharedModule

... I find that the `NativeGUI` tasks are executed before `SharedModule` which means that the `SharedModule` results aren't ready.

Bad.

Since the `dependency { ... }` stuff happens after plugins are installed (AFAIK) ... I'm guessing that the dependencies are connected after.

I need my tasks executed in order based on the dependency relations ... right? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a (scala) `TaskBag` that lazily registers a collection of all participating `Task` instances.
I add instances of my task to this, along with a handler for when a new task appears.

During configure, any task can include logic in the lambda to filter and act on *other tasks* and it will be executed as soon as both tasks are participating.

```
package peterlavalle

import java.util

import org.gradle.api.Task

object TaskBag {

    class AnchorExtension extends util.LinkedList[(Task, Task => Unit)]()

    /**
        * connect to the group of tasks
        */
    def apply(task: Task)(react: Task => Unit): Unit =
        synchronized {
            // lazily create the central anchor ... thing ...
            val anchor: AnchorExtension =
                task.getProject.getRootProject.getExtensions.findByType(classOf[AnchorExtension]) match {
                    case null =>
                        task.getProject.getRootProject.getExtensions.create(classOf[AnchorExtension].getName, classOf[AnchorExtension])
                    case anchor: AnchorExtension =>
                        anchor
                    }

            // show us off to the old ones
            anchor.foreach {
                case (otherTask, otherReact) =>
                    require(otherTask != task, "Don't double register a task!")
                    otherReact(task)
                    react(otherTask)
            }

            // add us to the list
            anchor.add(task -> react)
        }

}
```